# using multer to pass memoryStorage to express with ajax but req.file is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, file-upload

I know here are quite some posts in stackoverflow asking `req.file` is not defined, I looked through quite some and most of them are naming which I did not think it is how I am getting undefined though.

This is my html (pug)
I am not using a form as I an just using input on change

```
                    input#avatar-file(type='file', name='avatar')
                    button#add-avatar-btn.btn.btn-info Add Avatar
```

my ajax

```
s = {
    onClick: () => {
        $('#add-avatar-btn').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#avatar-file').click();
        });
    },
    onChange: () => {
        $('#avatar-file').on('change', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();

            let file = e.target.files;
            if (file.length === 1) {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('avatar', file);
                console.log(formData, 'formdata');  // this gives me -> FormData {} "formdata"
                s.runAjax(formData);
            }
        });
    },
    runAjax: dataValue => {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/avatar/upload',
            data: dataValue,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: data => {
                console.log(data, 'data success return');
            },
            error: err => {
                console.log(err, 'err return ');
            }
        });
    },
};

s.onClick();
s.onChange();
```

my express part

```
const multer  = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/avatar/upload',  upload.single('avatar'), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

        console.log(req.body.avatar, 'req.body.avatar');  // { avatarUrl: '[object FileList]' } 'req.body'
        console.log(req.files, 'request files');  // undefined
        console.log(req.file, 'single file');  // undefined
        return res.json({status: true});
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});
```

Which part am I doing this wrong though?
I am actually trying to use memory storge so it stores as buffer then upload it to s3 after instead of saving the image locally.

But I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: shouldn't you do `formData.append('avatar', file[0]);` instead of `formData.append('avatar', file);` and why are you doing `contentType: false,` in the ajax

Comment: @evgenifotia let me try the `file[0]` as for contentType, I was following a tutorial and it says `contentType - Set this to false because jQuery defaults to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and doesn't send the files. Also setting it to multipart/form-data doesn't seem to work either.`

Comment: @evgenifotia ah ! `file[0]` does solve it argggg, another stupid mistake.  Been looking into lots different forums some doesn't use `file[0]` and some do.  Do you want to post it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are sending an array instead of a file.

Do

```
formData.append('avatar', file[0]);
```

instead of

```
formData.append('avatar', file);
```